# How to correctly load Sql Server 2016 datatable to a wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

sorry for asking but i need some help.
I'm trying to load data from my datatable to a wpf datagrid.
Currently I'm doing it like this:
 xaml

```
<DataGrid Height="362" Width="auto" Name="grdAngebote" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" AlternationCount="2" RowEditEnding="grdAngebote_RowEditEnding"/>
```

cs

```
 private void fillDatagrid()
        {
            sqlQuery = string.Empty;
            using (sqlcon = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
            {
                sqlQuery = "Select ID, Angebotsnummer, Kundenname, Bauvorhaben, KundenstatusID as 'Kundenstatus', AquisekanalID as 'Aquisekanal', Ansprechpartner, AusführungszeitraumID as 'Ausführungszeitraum/Quartal', Auftragssumme, Zuschlagswahrscheinlichkeit as '%', KalkSumme, AngebotsstatusID as 'Angebotsstatus', Absagegrund From Angebote;";
                sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlcon);
                sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
                dt = new DataTable("Angebote");
                sqlda.Fill(dt);
                grdAngebote.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                string sum;
                sum = getSum();
                sqlcon.Close();
                Summe.Content = sum;
            }
        }
```

Some additional information:

```
private SqlConnection sqlcon;
private SqlCommand sqlcmd;
private SqlDataAdapter sqlda;
private DataTable dt;
```

This works for me but in every example on the internet i see that they use {Binding...} in order to see if some data in the grid has changed or something like that otherwise it is very hard to get e.g. changed data from a cell and update this to my SQL Server Database.
So i would like to update my program and also use bindings but how?

I would be grateful for every kind of help or tips.
Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Quite a big subject to cover off. Take a look at the relay command: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/icommand-and-relaycommand-in-wpf/ The binding you are talking about is the binding to a property, which you can then handle as required.

Comment: You do not  need to bind if an object has a ItemSource or DataSource property.

Comment: thanks guys for the fast answers! i know this topic is quite big. so if i do not need bindings how can i get changed values e.g. after the Roweditending event? i tried it like this:  if(e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
            {
                Angebot a = new Angebot();
                a = e.Row.Item as Angebot;
                if (a != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(a.Kundenname);
                }
            }  Am i missing something because my object is always NULL.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model class that initializes and exposes the data that you want to bind to:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        fill();
    }

    private void fill()
    {
        sqlQuery = string.Empty;
        using (sqlcon = new SqlConnection(sqlConString))
        {
            sqlQuery = "Select ID, Angebotsnummer, Kundenname, Bauvorhaben, KundenstatusID as 'Kundenstatus', AquisekanalID as 'Aquisekanal', Ansprechpartner, AusführungszeitraumID as 'Ausführungszeitraum/Quartal', Auftragssumme, Zuschlagswahrscheinlichkeit as '%', KalkSumme, AngebotsstatusID as 'Angebotsstatus', Absagegrund From Angebote;";
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlcon);
            sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            dt = new DataTable("Angebote");
            sqlda.Fill(dt);
            DataView = dt.DefaultView;

            string sum;
            Sum = getSum();
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }

    public DataView DataView { get; private set; }
    public string Sum { get; private set; }
}
```

Set the `DataContext` of your window to an instance of the view model class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Window31ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Bind to properties of the view model in your XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="grdAngebote" ItemsSource="{Binding DataView} " .../>
...
<Label x:Name="Summe" Content="{Binding Sum}" />
```